# Domain name - multiple host - multiple server?

Tags: domain, domain-name, dns-hosting

I currently own a domain name `mydomain.com` at goDaddy and I have a web server (at thePlanet) `mydomain.com` which serve a website from `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` with Apache.
I now have a new server in an other hosting company and I would like to access this server with `sandbox.mydomain.com` and serve a website from `sandbox.mydomain.com`.

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to create an A record in your DNS server for `sandbox.mydomain.com` pointing to the IP address of your new server.

Comment: +1 Beat my 2 seconds. :(

Comment: Do I need to do something with goDaddy?
When you say DNS server, you say DNS server of the new hosting company?

Comment: @nejisail. You need to do this via your goDaddy control panel since they store your DNS settings. You have only one DNS service for your complete domain. You can find out how with goDaddy by looking at their help guide with regard to DNS here: http://help.godaddy.com/article/681

Comment: It seems that my DNS settings are manage in ThePlanet. Is it possible?

Comment: do 'dig -t ns mydomain.com' and you'll see what nameservers you are using and hopefully that will tell you where you need to modify the dns.

As well as adding this dns record, you'll also need to ensure the new host is configured to respond to sandbox.mydomain.com.

Comment: dig give ns1.theplanet.com so I have to modify dns on thePlanet.